# Will Alamofire be ready for working with Apple Relay?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I read from MWC 2021 that Apple will introduce Apple Relay, which is another spet between the devices and the network to get more privacy and security. This feature will be in production on the iOS 15 release. But I'm working with Alamofire library and I would like to know if this feature will be implemented and when. And the most important part, what will be the impact.

Comment: How about asking the developer?

Comment: @vadian when I tried to ask on Alamofire they redirect me to StackOverflow...

Comment: No such question has been asked on the Alamofire GitHub. I would suggest you do some research and try it out rather than asking, as that's all we'd do, so I'd appreciate not having to fulfill your curiosity.